# How to hook into the power button (lock button) with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, locking, hook

Since I am developing a cross mobile application that runs over iOS and Android.

So, I wanted to be attached to the power button in order to make some proccessing whenever a user presses the power button. My idea is using javascript instead of creating a native plugin (iOS AND Android) in order to keep my app as generic as possible so I wanted to know if phonegap provides any way to do that?

Thanks!

German L.

Answer (score 1):

For current versions (=>3.5.0) of Cordova/PhoneGap, the API URL changed to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events
(Sry, not enough reputation for commenting on Simon MacDonald's answer instead)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC when you click the lock/power button you should get a "pause" event from PhoneGap.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Comment: yes, that is true, but I need a way to discriminate when the user pressed the home button and when the user pressed the lock/power button... since phonegap pause event is called whether the home or lock/power button is pressed..

Comment: I found a way to determine whenever the power/lock button was pressed, the thing is that you cannot do it using what phonegap provides, instead you need you add native Android code to acomplish that. The idea es using the class PowerManagment provided by Android´s framework. 

for example:

Comment: Example:

@Override
protected void onPause() {
     PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     if (powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
      //onPause called due to home button was pressed...
     }
     else {
              //onPause called due to lock/power button was pressed...
     }
     super.onPause();
    }